# Can the adverb "exclusively" in the sentence be replaced with an adjective without changing the meaning of the sentence?

Tags: adjectives, adverbs, gerunds, register

I came across this sentence in an [online article](https://www.usatoday.com/story/life/allthemoms/2018/05/17/newborns-allergy-development-prevention/620669002/).

> Some medical literature has found that **exclusively** breastfeeding during the first four to six months of life may decrease your baby’s risk of developing eczema, asthma and cow’s milk allergy.

I am not quite sure why the adverb **exclusively** is used here to modify the gerund **breastfeeding** in preference to **exclusive**. The adverb, of course, works, but my question is would the adjective work just the same?

Comment: This is not an answer because I can give no authority for it. I would never use **exclusive** in this sentence, but **exclusively** does not seem quite right either because the contrary idea of **promiscuously** breast feeding strikes me as very weird. Nor do I think that breast feeding is even what is meant. I think what is meant is that **some medical studies have found that a diet consisting exclusively  of human milk during ... may prevent ...**. Obviously **exclusively** is correct there whereas **exclusive** is not. Nor is the method by which the milk is delivered relevant. Bad prose.

Comment: @JeffMorrow Just so I understand you, are you saying an adjective shouldn't modify a gerund?

Comment: Not at all. I can think of many examples where adjectives modify gerunds, *e.g.* **quick thinking**. I did not give a formal answer just because I could not articulate any grammatical rule that makes **exclusive breastfeeding** wrong. It sounds, however, unidiomatic to me. My best guess is that it sounds unidiomatic because the intended meaning does not concern  the act of breast feeding at all, but concerns a diet consisting exclusively of human milk. The mind figures out what is meant and inserts what is required, namely an adverb modifying the participle **consisting**. I may well be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The way I interpret the phrase is that a baby's health is improved if its only source of nutrients comes from breast milk during its first four to six months.

In that interpretation, **exclusively** makes sense. (In other words, it is breastfed and only breastfed.)

But the sentence has some issues with its grammar—regardless of which word is used.

It would make a lot more sense if it read:

> ***exclusively*** breastfeeding ***your baby*** during ***its*** first four to six months . . .

Switching from **exclusively** to **exclusive** would also work with another tweak to the sentence:

> ***the exclusive*** breastfeeding ***of your baby*** during ***its*** first four to six months . . .

(Without the mention of the baby immediately after *breastfeeding*, it *could* be interpreted as talking about the mother's act of breastfeeding alone—without regard to any particular baby.)

Answer (score 1):

The practical meaning here is "breastfeeding only" as distinct from breastfeeding supplemented with "baby formula" containing soy, whey, lactose, and various oils.

The phrase you propose, **exclusive breastfeeding**, sounds a little comical, like the breast is a night-club for *glitterati*. A baby "needs to know somebody" to latch on.

A simpler phrase than **exclusively breastfeeding** might have been

... has shown that **giving the baby only breast-milk** during the first four to six months...

but that would be perceived as "non-scientific" language and not pass muster as too informal.

P.S. **only** must precede **breast-milk** so as not to be misunderstood as a restriction that goes with **(only) during the first four to six months**.